# When is the concavity of a differentiable function not defined? What does it signify graphically?

Tags: derivatives, continuity

Suppose I have a function $f(x)$ such that $f(x)= x^2 $ for $ x>0$ and $f(x)= -x^2 $ for $ x\leqslant0$.
Thus we have  $ f'(x) = |2x|$ .

Thus at $x=0$ value of $f''(x)$ is not defined.
This implies that the graph's concavity is undefined at $x=0$.

I do not understand what this means graphically. I mean, the curves of $f(x)$ and $x^3$ are so similar... still one of them has an undefined concavity.
[image]

Comment: Both of your functions have stationary inflection points at $x = 0$, and I'd say that neither function has a defined concavity at $x = 0$.

Comment: @travis f''(x^3) = 6x, which is zero at x=0

Comment: If i differentiate my function in a piecewise approach, then i get for x-> 0+ f'(x) = 2x and x-> 0-, f'(x) = -2x. On a second time differentiation, we have f''(x) =2 for x->0+ and f''(x) = -2 for x->0- so we cannot define f''(x) at x=0

Comment: Right. So, is $x \mapsto x^3$ concave up or concave down at $x = 0$?

Comment: I believe at f(x) = x3 is both concave up and down, like a linear function....at x=0

Comment: In that case, what is your definition of concavity of a function $f$ at a point $a$ in its domain?

Comment: Concave upward if f'(x) is an increasing function @travis

Answer (score 1):

The point you are missing is that both $x\cdot|x|$ and $x^3$ have undefined concavity at $x=0$, in fact, both have inflection points at $x=0$. Concavity is not defined in terms of differentiability, rather if a function is differentiable, it gives a convenient test for (local) concavity.

The (local) concavity of a differentiable is not defined if and only if the derivative is not (locally) monotone.

What it means graphically is complicated. For example, $x^3$ has an inflection point at $x=0$, i.e. a point at which the concavity changes. However, there are other functions, i.e. $f(x)=x^{10}\sin(x^{-1})$ for $x\neq 0$ and $f(0)=0$, for which around $x=0$ the function is neither convex nor concave, and the point it is not an inflection point either.

Answer (score -1):

Your function does have a derivative since you defined a value for 0, at x=0 your function is $f(0)=-0^2=0$ this means that the derivative of 0 at your function is: $f'(0)=-2*0 =0$,

you could also define this function as $f(x)=x^3/|x|$, we can take the derivative of this the classic way:

$((x+n)^3/|x+n|-(x-n)^3/|x-n|)/2n$

then we plug in zero and simplify:

$(n^3/|n|-(-n)^3/|-n|)/2n = n^2/|n|$

and since both $\lim n\to +0 \ (n^2/|n|) = 0$ and $\lim n\to -0 \ (n^2/|n|) = 0$, we can conclude that the derivative of your function at 0 is 0

Comment: Lhd is not equal to rhd

Comment: @SageofSevenPaths both limits approach 0? It's clear thag the derivative is 0? Or am I missing something?

Comment: If i differentiate my function in a piecewise approach, then i get for x-> 0+ f'(x) = 2x and x-> 0-, f'(x) = -2x. On a second time differentiation, we have f''(x) =2 for x->0+ and f''(x) = -2 for x->0- so we cannot define f''(x) at x=0

Comment: @SageofSevenPaths I see! Then I don't think there's a derivative, kinda like with |x| at 0, I'm sorry for wasting your time

Comment: No its all right sejr 